# Getting error in apt-get autoremove. How can I remove it?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I got the following error message when trying to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` :

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up todoist (1.17.0) ... 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/todoist' No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package todoist (--configure):
 installed todoist package post-installation script subprocess returned error    
exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:
 todoist
E: Sub- process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: can you copy paste the whole content in your terminal and paste as text by editing your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and type the following command: `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt purge todolist` and copy-paste the output of your terminal as text, then use the `{}` button to format it as a terminal output, then leave a message @Fabby

Answer (score 0):

There is no package named todoist in the default Ubuntu repositories which is why autoremove is unable to automatically remove it. Try to remove todoist manually. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge todoist
```

If the above command doesn't work use Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) to remove todoist instead. Open *Synaptic* -> click the *Status* button in the lower left corner -> click *Installed (local or obsolete)* and search for the todoist package in the center pane. If you find the todoist package, click the checkbox on the left side of the package and select *Mark for Removal* to remove it.

[image: Synaptic]

Comment: There is no package named todolist in the default Ubuntu repositories either.